# How to redirect from native android to react native

Tags: android, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm new to React Native and I have two screens in React Native mobile app. Screen 1 in built in RN (Javascript) whereas other Screen 2 is built in android native code(java). App has to navigate from Screen 1 to Screen 2 and come back with some contextual data(acquired at Screen 2) to Screen 1. I have navigated from RN from Screen1 to native code to screen2 but now I want to navigate from from screen 2 to screen 1 with some data.

tried this but getting event but need to redirect so any help.
(java code)
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
        map.putString("key1", "Value1");

    try {
       getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()   
      .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
      .emit("customEventName", map);

        } catch (Exception e){
          Log.e("ReactNative", "Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

RN code:
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

```
 componentWillMount(){DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('customEventName', function(e: Event) {})};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch some data from your new activity(Screen 2) then, use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity and override the onResult method.